# Weird Apache Access log

Tags: apache-2.2

This is the current access log for my site rishavrastogi.com

```
196.201.39.98 - - [23/Sep/2010:12:08:16 +0000] "POST http://www.tagged.com/api/?application_id=user&format=json&session_token=c85rqoo30bqrc7jnpdmlp57d83 HTTP/1.1" 200 472 "http://www.tagged.com/profile.html?view=mini&uid=5411562347" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"
41.218.239.57 - - [23/Sep/2010:12:08:16 +0000] "GET http://c5.zedo.com/ads5/d/3609/172/496/111/109/i.js?z=0750 HTTP/1.1" 200 2426 "http://c5.zedo.com/jsc/c5/ff2.html?n=496;c=111/109;s=1;d=14;w=728;h=90;p=1001;q=messages&t=1826" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.19) Gecko/2010031422 AskTbBT5/3.8.0.12304 Firefox/3.0.19"
96.31.68.38 - - [23/Sep/2010:12:08:16 +0000] "GET http://ad.yieldmanager.com/imp?Z=728x90&s=734666&_salt=5712275195&B=12&m=2&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.alltubedl.com%2F&r=0 HTTP/1.1" 302 - "http://ad.reachjunction.com/st?ad_type=iframe&ad_size=728x90§ion=734666" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.7) Gecko/20100713 Firefox/3.6.7 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
109.86.209.238 - - [23/Sep/2010:12:08:15 +0000] "POST http://my.mail.ru/cgi-bin/my/ajax?ajax_call=1&func_name=perl_photo_for_vote HTTP/1.1" 200 1388 "-" "Opera/9.25 (Windows NT 5.1; U; ru)"
80.87.81.150 - - [23/Sep/2010:12:08:16 +0000] "GET http://b.scorecardresearch.com/b?c1=2&c2=3000023&rn=0.0978174457108752&c7=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.cnet.com%2F1770-20_4-0.html%3Fquery%3Dhp%2Bcolor%2Blaserjet%2B4650%2Bdrivers%26tag%3Dsrch%26searchtype%3Ddownloads%26filterName%3Dplatform%253DWindows%252CWebware%26filter%3Dplatform%253DWindows%252CWebware&c3=&c4=&c5=&c6=&c10=&c15=&c16=&c8=hp%20color%20laserjet%204650%20drivers%20downloads%20-%20Free%20software%20downloads%20and%20software%20reviews%20-%20CNET&c9=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.cnet.com%2Fwindows%2F&cv=1.8 HTTP/1.1" 204 - "http://download.cnet.com/1770-20_4-0.html?query=hp+color+laserjet+4650+drivers&tag=srch&searchtype=downloads&filterName=platform%3DWindows%2CWebware&filter=platform%3DWindows%2CWebware" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; GTB6.5; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; AskTB5.6)"
41.218.239.57 - - [23/Sep/2010:12:08:16 +0000] "GET http://l5.zedo.com/log/p.gif?a=276291;;r=1;x=1817;g=172,0;c=496000111,496000111;i=21;n=496;q=74;i=67;u=odGRtgoBADYAACZsGtMAAAHP~080310;1=5;2=1;e=i;s=1;g=172;w=6;m=502;q=messages%26t;z=0.144442904864648060.2285379657722636 HTTP/1.1" 200 43 "http://c5.zedo.com/jsc/c5/ff2.html?n=496;c=111/109;s=1;d=7;w=160;h=600;p=1001;q=messages&t=1826" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.19) Gecko/2010031422 AskTbBT5/3.8.0.12304 Firefox/3.0.19"
210.51.24.171 - - [23/Sep/2010:12:08:16 +0000] "GET http://servedby.adxpose.com/adxpose/find_ad.js HTTP/1.0" 200 1179 "http://www.smartertravel.com" "mozilla/4.0 (compatible; msie 6.0; windows nt 5.1)"
195.248.234.33 - - [23/Sep/2010:12:08:16 +0000] "GET http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?hl=en&q=cache%3Awww.gismps.ru%2Fcontent%2Fview%2F47%2F43%2F HTTP/1.1" 200 28502 "http://www.google.com/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; MyIE2; MRA 4.8 (build 01709); .NET CLR 1.1.4322; InfoPath.1)"
173.224.218.97 - - [23/Sep/2010:12:08:16 +0000] "GET http://www.mothering.com/discussions/image.php?type=hv&hash=e1799ea01f0e33be396911208b60b5c8 HTTP/1.0" 200 18619 "http://www.mothering.com/discussions/register.php?s=86a3b445505cba446c020f241927bdc9" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1) Opera 7.54 [en]"
41.218.239.57 - - [23/Sep/2010:12:08:17 +0000] "GET http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=ca-pub-6547074035899916&format=160x600_as&output=html&h=600&w=160&channel=9224992124&ad_type=text_image&ea=0&alternate_ad_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tagged.com%2Fad_redirect_160.html&cust_age=1001&cust_gender=2&flash=10.0.45&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tagged.com%2Fmessages.html%3FmsgId%3D172502289400064038%26ft%3D1%26ect%3D3wdnu58i%26al%3D1%26fid%3DF318F0FDD1CC746D%26tn%3DbWVzc2FnZXNfbmV3LTEtMy0x%26linkId%3Dmessage_link_0&dt=1285227664939&shv=r20100909&jsv=r20100917&correlator=1285227664944&frm=1&adk=1240161899&ga_vid=1789046811.1285227665&ga_sid=1285227665&ga_hid=1991724694&ga_fc=0&u_tz=270&u_his=1&u_java=0&u_h=768&u_w=1024&u_ah=738&u_aw=1024&u_cd=32&u_nplug=18&u_nmime=110&biw=-12245933&bih=-12245933&ifk=2364570421&fu=0&ifi=1&dtd=87 HTTP/1.1" 200 1264 "http://c5.zedo.com/jsc/c5/ff2.html?n=496;c=111/109;s=1;d=7;w=160;h=600;p=1001;q=messages&t=1826" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.19) Gecko/2010031422 AskTbBT5/3.8.0.12304 Firefox/3.0.19"
196.201.39.98 - - [23/Sep/2010:12:08:17 +0000] "GET http://www.facebook.com/extern/login_status.php?api_key=123049054388972&display=hidden&extern=2&locale=en_US&method=auth.status&next=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tagged.com%2Fprofile.html%3Fview%3Dmini%26uid%3D10651379%26fb_xd_fragment%23%3F%3D%26cb%3Df2f495d99aadbc%26relation%3Dopener%26transport%3Dfragment%26frame%3Df33d742667bde0c%26result%3D%2522xxRESULTTOKENxx%2522&no_session=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tagged.com%2Fprofile.html%3Fview%3Dmini%26uid%3D10651379%26fb_xd_fragment%23%3F%3D%26cb%3Df4dfbb0b484aa%26relation%3Dparent%26transport%3Dfragment%26frame%3Df33d742667bde0c&no_user=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tagged.com%2Fprofile.html%3Fview%3Dmini%26uid%3D10651379%26fb_xd_fragment%23%3F%3D%26cb%3Df2ba4a89a3eca84%26relation%3Dparent%26transport%3Dfragment%26frame%3Df33d742667bde0c&ok_session=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tagged.com%2Fprofile.html%3Fview%3Dmini%26uid%3D10651379%26fb_xd_fragment%23%3F%3D%26cb%3Df1de62e7f210464%26relation%3Dparent%26transport%3Dfragment%26frame%3Df33d742667bde0c&sdk=joey&session_version=3 HTTP/1.1" 302 20 "http://www.tagged.com/profile.html?view=mini&uid=10651379" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"
41.218.239.57 - - [23/Sep/2010:12:08:17 +0000] "GET http://c5.zedo.com/ads5/d/2329/172/496/111/109/i.js?z=0750 HTTP/1.1" 200 1852 "http://c5
```

I can't understand what might be reason of this happening and how can i stop this ?

I fixed and my server is not a open proxy. But I still get such requests. I setup ProxyRequests Off and Made sure its secure. All of such requests now keep getting a 404 or a 200 standard "It Works" Apache responses. How Can I stop even these ?

Comment: did you solve your issue?

Comment: @jamie you can setup firewall, which do help solving part of the problem. But makes the server setup really complicated. Generally people troll for open-proxies all the time.

Comment: may be you can go to #apache i think on the irc and discuss this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those looks like attempts to leverage mod_proxy to get at other parts of the 'net. An incorrectly configured mod_proxy config makes a web-server an open proxy, very valuable for people trying to look like they're not from the place that they actually are. I can't be sure, but that's sure what it looks like to me.

Apache mod_proxy documentation, on access-control:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html#access

Comment: Updated my question. I am sure its not an Open Proxy. ProxyReuqests is set to off

Comment: @Rishav: Ask a new question imo. Your initial has already been answered, and accepted.